# how do i load csv into array?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using `pandas` to load csv files containing questions/answers and assigning them to dict.

```
kids_csv_file = pd.read_csv(...) #columns Questions, SubQuestions, Answers

questions_dict = dict()

for i in ... :
_key = kids_csv_file.Questions[i] + '-' + kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i]
questions_dict[_key] = kids_csv_file.Answers[i];
```

I am getting:

> TypeError: must be str, not numpy.int64

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned before, `kids_csv_file.Questions[i]` is not a string, so python can't use the string's Plus operator to concatenate it to other strings. you can use the format method, though:

```
questions_dict['{}-{}'.format(kids_csv_file.Questions[i], kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i])] = kids_csv_file.Answers[i];
```

or better yet, create the index in a different line:

```
index = '{}-{}'.format(kids_csv_file.Questions[i], kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i])
questions_dict[index] = kids_csv_file.Answers[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because kids_csv_file.Questions[i] + '-' + kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i] is not a string.
When you type `kids_csv_file.Questions[i] + '-' + kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i]`
python thinks, that string '-' must be joined with object `kids_csv_file.Questions[i]` and `kids_csv_file.SubQuestion[i]`

step 1) create string in separate line

step 2) append to dict your value